# Double File name when using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to save a file using this code:

```
//file save first time
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
//set name for default file for the file chooser.
chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(communicator.getFileName()));

int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
        //write log message to textfield
        communicator.writeToField("[Save File]:   Saving file at: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        //setup output stream
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+".bin"));
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        //get the object to serialize
        oos.writeObject(communicator.getCurrentFileObject());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} else
    //write log message to textfield
    communicator.writeToField("[Save File]:   Operation aborted by user...");
```

when I use this the output of the code is `[Save File]:   Saving file at: /home/name/documents/test.bin`

but whenever I go and look at the actuall file inside the folder it's name is `testtest.bin`. so the name gets repeated twice. What can be the problem here?

Comment: What you've reported doesn't make sense - if the message was "Saving file at: /home/name/documents/test.bin" and the actual file were called "test.bin.bin" that would make sense, given that you're not adding ".bin" in the message, but you *are* in the `File` constructor...

Comment: yeah but that's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When

```
chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

already delivers the output

```
/home/name/documents/test.bin
```

as your logging shows. Why do you then add another ".bin"?

```
new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+".bin")
```

I reckon the additional ".bin" causes your problem. Just leave it out. You don't need it as your logging shows.

Comment: This helped by finding the solution but it was not the problem itself. I went around the entire program and found that there was some place that the name would get added to the path but it was all ready there,,,